# CentOS: After Kernel Update system does not boot (/dev/md2 does not exist)

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel, dracut

after doing a kernel-update (only via `yum update`) my centOS 7 (64bit) does no longer boot.

[image]

I now booted into rescue-mode and tried to mount /dev/md2 - this worked fine:

[image]

Any ideas what I could do here?

Comment: Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. Also use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Comment: Which Part Shorts be formatted in another way? Did you mention that there are 2 screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Do as it suggests and make a copy of the rdsosreport.txt to /boot.

You could try booting the previous kernel
- Reset the system, you should get an opportunity to select which kernel to boot, select an earlier one and see what happens.

Comment: Problem exists on all kernels :(